# How to handle unhandled rejections in Jest and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, error-handling, jestjs, ts-jest

#### Error

I could not figure out how to handle the unhandled rejections on an open-source project.
I have this kind of errors (54 already...):

```
(node:12836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Fake test error: send
(node:12836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `
--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 54)
```

#### A test

A test example logging the message above:

```
it(`should log about sending a message`, async (): Promise<void> => {
    expect.assertions(3);

    await expect(service.handleChannelMessage(anyDiscordMessage)).rejects.toThrow(new Error(`Fake test error: send`));
    expect(loggerServiceDebugSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(loggerServiceDebugSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, {
        context: `DiscordMessageService`,
        extendedContext: true,
        message: `context-[dummy-id] text-sending message...`,
    } as ILoggerLog);
});
```

I thought that this specific syntax with the await and the rejects.toThrow was a good way to catch those, and I tried other syntaxes (some that I dislike and are not recommended by default linter configuration for example) but anyway I still could not find a way to not have Jest crying about this.

#### Jest

I run the command `npm run jest --watchAll --unhandled-rejections=strict` to start the tests.

If somehow this is useful, here is the Jest configuration:

```
// For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

module.exports = {
  // All imported modules in your tests should be mocked automatically
  automock: false,

  // Stop running tests after `n` failures
  bail: false,

  // Respect "browser" field in package.json when resolving modules
  // browser: false,

  cache: true,

  // The directory where Jest should store its cached dependency information
  cacheDirectory: `./.cache-jest`,

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: false,

  // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
  // collectCoverageFrom: undefined,

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: `coverage`,

  // An array of regexp pattern strings used to skip coverage collection
  // coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "\\\\node_modules\\\\"
  // ],

  // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
  coverageReporters: [`json`, `text-summary`, `lcov`],

  // An object that configures minimum threshold enforcement for coverage results
  // coverageThreshold: undefined,

  // A path to a custom dependency extractor
  // dependencyExtractor: undefined,

  displayName: {
    color: `magenta`,
    name: `Sonia`,
  },

  // Make calling deprecated APIs throw helpful error messages
  errorOnDeprecated: true,

  // Force coverage collection from ignored files using an array of glob patterns
  // forceCoverageMatch: [],

  // A path to a module which exports an async function that is triggered once before all test suites
  // globalSetup: undefined,

  // A path to a module which exports an async function that is triggered once after all test suites
  // globalTeardown: undefined,

  // A set of global variables that need to be available in all test environments
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      compiler: `ttypescript`,
    },
  },

  // The maximum amount of workers used to run your tests. Can be specified as % or a number. E.g. maxWorkers: 10% will use 10% of your CPU amount + 1 as the maximum worker number. maxWorkers: 2 will use a maximum of 2 workers.
  // maxWorkers: "50%",

  maxConcurrency: 5,

  // An array of directory names to be searched recursively up from the requiring module's location
  moduleDirectories: [`./node_modules`],

  // A map from regular expressions to module names that allow to stub out resources with a single module
  // moduleNameMapper: {},

  // An array of regexp pattern strings, matched against all module paths before considered 'visible' to the module loader
  // modulePathIgnorePatterns: [],

  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: [`js`, `json`, `ts`, `node`],

  // Activates notifications for test results
  notify: true,

  // An enum that specifies notification mode. Requires { notify: true }
  notifyMode: `failure-change`,

  // Run tests from one or more projects
  // projects: undefined,

  // A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
  preset: `ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts`,

  prettierPath: `prettier`,

  // Use this configuration option to add custom reporters to Jest
  reporters: [
    [
      `jest-silent-reporter`,
      {
        showPaths: true,
        showWarnings: true,
        useDots: true,
      },
    ],
  ],

  // Automatically reset mock state between every test
  resetMocks: true,

  // A path to a custom resolver
  // resolver: undefined,

  // Reset the module registry before running each individual test
  resetModules: false,

  // The root directory that Jest should scan for tests and modules within
  // rootDir: undefined,

  // Automatically restore mock state between every test
  restoreMocks: true,

  // Allows you to use a custom runner instead of Jest's default test runner
  // runner: "jest-runner",

  // A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
  roots: [`./src`, `./scripts`],

  // The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  setupFiles: [`./config.ts`],

  // A list of paths to snapshot serializer modules Jest should use for snapshot testing
  // snapshotSerializers: [],

  // Prevent tests from printing messages through the console
  silent: true,

  // A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: [`./__tests__/setup.js`],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: `node`,

  // Options that will be passed to the testEnvironment
  // testEnvironmentOptions: {},

  // Adds a location field to test results
  // testLocationInResults: false,

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  // testMatch: [
  //   "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
  //   "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  // ],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
  // testPathIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "\\\\node_modules\\\\"
  // ],

  // The regexp pattern or array of patterns that Jest uses to detect test files
  // testRegex: [],

  // This option allows the use of a custom results processor
  // testResultsProcessor: undefined,

  // This option allows use of a custom test runner
  // testRunner: "jasmine2",

  // This option sets the URL for the jsdom environment. It is reflected in properties such as location.href
  // testURL: "http://localhost",

  testTimeout: 5000,

  // Setting this value to "fake" allows the use of fake timers for functions such as "setTimeout"
  timers: `fake`,

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  // transformIgnorePatterns: [
  //   "\\\\node_modules\\\\"
  // ],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all modules before the module loader will automatically return a mock for them
  // unmockedModulePathPatterns: undefined,

  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  transform: {
    ".ts": `ts-jest`,
  },

  // An array of regexp patterns that are matched against all source file paths before re-running tests in watch mode
  // watchPathIgnorePatterns: [],

  // Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  verbose: true,

  // Whether to use watchman for file crawling
  watchman: true,
};
```

#### Dependencies

```
jest: 26.1.0
ts-jest: 26.1.1
```

#### Repository

If someone need a real case testing example, the [project is public on GitHub](https://github.com/Sonia-corporation/il-est-midi-discord).

Thanks!